# htaccess Language redirect with query parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm currently redirecting to a language subsite by looking for a query parameter. This works but I would like to add support for more languages.

Current working code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ll=es$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/es/)
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com/es/$1 [R=302,L,QSA]
```

I can make it search for any of the other languages, but when it comes to inserting them back into the rules I get stuck.

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ll=(es|fr|de)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/$2/)
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com/$2/$1 [R=302,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For back-referencing matches in `RewriteCond`, you use `%N` and not `$N`<sup>[read more](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)</sup>. The rules would thus be:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)ll=(es|fr|de)\b [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/%1/$1 [R=302,L,QSA]
```

The `(?:)` will not store the match for back-referencing.

Comment: This seems to be giving a redirection loop from the second line. If I replace the `!^/%1/` with `!^/es/` it works but obviously only for that path.

Comment: @Justin You can use `!^/(?:es|fr|de)/` instead in the second line. I'll see why it isn't working as given above.